# Javascript sort array of objects by KEY

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an array like this DESC by the key "score"

```
[{user : 'a' , score : 45},{user: 'c', score: 90},{user : 'r' , score : 56}]
```

result would be

```
[{user: 'c', score: 90},{user : 'r' , score : 56}, {user : 'a' , score : 45}]
```

What's the best practice ?

i tried underscore _.sortBy function whithout success

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) passing your own comparison function,

```js
function compare(a, b) {
  return b.score - a.score;
}

const arr = [{user : 'a' , score : 45},{user: 'c', score: 90},{user : 'r' , score : 56}];

const sorted = arr.sort(compare);
console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: this looks like ASC i am wondering for DESC order how it is

Comment: oops sorry, just updated my answer